# How can i restrict the type of a field in an interface so that it only depends on other fields?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
interface T {
    name: string[];
    pick: T['name'][number]
}
```

and for example if i choose name to be `['a', 'b']`, pick can only be `a` or `b`

how can i do this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: if name is 'abc', pick can be 'a', 'b', or 'c'?

Comment: no no the answer that you deleted is correct just return it back please

Comment: i've undeleted it, but please edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You have to make the `name` field generic, so: `interface T<N extends string[]>{name: N, pick: T<N>['name'][number]}` And if the type `N` is a tuple, eg `['a', 'b']` then `pick` will be `'a' | 'b'`

Comment: Sry, didn't see the other comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with generics like so:

```js
interface MyType<T extends string> {
    name: T[];
    pick: T[number]
}


const v1: MyType<'abc' | 'bcd'> = {
  name: ['abc', 'bcd'],
  pick: 'a'
}
```